# Python : How to get non initialised attribute from one class to another one

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm trying to send a variable from one class to another one. The problem is that i can't use the **init** constructor as my variable isn't defined at the beginning. If the user press one button, it will call a function (in the first class) and the variable will get the value calculated in that fonction. I need to get that variable in another class but i can't do that.

```
class Fenetre_P(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fenetre_P, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.chk_dark = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Theme sombre", self)      
        self.chk_dark.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.SetBarValues())
    def SetBarValues(self):
        amax = 50

class Fenetre_M(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fenetre_M, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        ...
        def test(self):
            print(amax)
```

amax is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help, although you could use other OOP concepts like composition to get the job done

```
class Fenetre_P(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    amax=0
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fenetre_P, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.chk_dark = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Theme sombre", self)      
        self.chk_dark.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.SetBarValues())
    def SetBarValues(self):
        self.amax = 50

class Fenetre_M(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,amax):
        super(Fenetre_M, self).__init__()
        self.amax=amax
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        ...
        def test(self):
            print(self.amax)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables come into existence when you assign them . It is not necessary for them to be defined in the **init** method only. Looks like what you need is to make amax an instance variable and pass an instance of `Fenetre_P` to  `Fenetre_M`.

```
>>> class A:
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.a = 3
...    def some(self):
...       self.b = 9
...
>>> ainstance = A()
>>> dir(ainstance)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'a', 'some']
>>> ainstance.a
3
>>> ainstance.some()
>>> dir(ainstance)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'a', 'b', 'some']
>>> ainstance.b
9
```